# Prevent redundancy in writing function in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to using ASP.NET and C#. I just want to ask if is there any way to put this line of code into a single public void function and whenever I need it, I will just call the function to to avoid redundancy. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Edit.Enabled = false;
        Save.Enabled = true;
        Cancel.Enabled = true;
        TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        TextBox2.Enabled = true;
        TextBox3.Enabled = true;
        TextBox4.Enabled = true;
        TextBox5.Enabled = true;
}

protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Edit.Enabled = true;
    Save.Enabled = false;
    Cancel.Enabled = false;

    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
    TextBox2.Enabled = false;
    TextBox3.Enabled = false;
    TextBox4.Enabled = false;
    TextBox5.Enabled = false;
}

protected void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Edit.Enabled = true;
    Save.Enabled = false;
    Cancel.Enabled = false;

    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
    TextBox2.Enabled = false;
    TextBox3.Enabled = false;
    TextBox4.Enabled = false;
    TextBox5.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetEnabled(true);
}

protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    SetEnabled(false);
}

 protected void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetEnabled(false);
}

private void SetEnabled(bool editEnabled)
{
    Edit.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    Save.Enabled = editEnabled;
    Cancel.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    TextBox1.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    TextBox2.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    TextBox3.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    TextBox4.Enabled = !editEnabled;
    TextBox5.Enabled = !editEnabled;
}
```

Comment: and why `Edit.Enabled =` is not inside `Set` as well? ... also it doesn't do the same as OP code

Comment: @Selvin. Thanks your your comment. I think I adjusted it.

Comment: @Selvin, also just now noticed your comment on the other answer... :)

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer, it works i just adjusted the code to fit what I need. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one function as handler for all three buttons by writing the handler as follows

```
protected void EditSaveCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Edit.Enabled = (sender != Edit);
    Save.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    Cancel.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    TextBox1.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    TextBox2.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    TextBox3.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    TextBox4.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
    TextBox5.Enabled = !Edit.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: can I use this even if these three buttons have there different respective function? (example: when save button is clicked it will save changes and when cancel is clicked it will cancel out the changes in the textboxes )

Comment: Yes you can, just pass along the `sender` and `e` from the original handler.

Comment: it would be better to move this to another method like `void SetEditable(bool editable) { }` and then use it like `SetEditable(true/false)` from clicks

Comment: @Selvin "better" is almost always a matter of personal taste. At least without an explination of why it would be better.

Comment: method may explain what it does by it's name, it can be reused with another event like fx some dropdown chanege ... I would connect both ... one click even and another method :) (as long as save/cancel/edit doesn't need any other action)

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer, it works i just adjusted the code to fit what I need. thanks again.